# Malformed answer links on user page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

In the user page, links to answers are malformed. It happens in both profile and activity tabs:

```
/questions/2482348/run-c-or-c-file-as-a-script/29709521#29709521
```

instead of

```
/questions/2482348/run-c-or-c-file-as-a-script#29709521
```

Not really a defect, but it's annoying.

Answer (score 3):

The answer's ID has to be part of the path, not *just* in the fragment. Otherwise, the server wouldn't be able to load the correct page in cases where there are multiple pages of answers.

Comment: Maybe would be better if aditional pages were loaded on demand from a fragment `#page=2`? URL routing with javascript could help with these tiny glitches.

Comment: Uh, no. For starters, answers are not fixed to any page. Also, JavaScript loading is inefficient when you're already loading a full page of answers.

Comment: @Kanvuanza: That would needlessly make JavaScript required for reading. Thus, won't happen.

Comment: I'm ok with `etcetera/29709521` and/or  `etcetera#29709521`, but not with `etcetera/29709521#29709521`.

Comment: The server needs the answer's ID to load the correct page of answer, and the browser needs the fragment to scroll to the correct answer's anchor after the page is loaded. But why can't we just `window.location.href = "#29709521"`at end of `window.onload()`?

Comment: The correct page would be loaded even if JavaScript was disabled.